# Git versioning with setuptools in pyproject.toml

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, gitversion, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to build a few packages with an automatic versioning set by `setuptools-git-versioning`. Unfortunately, even following the documentation and the very few resources online, I can't manage to make this versioning work.

`pyproject.toml:`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "setuptools-git-versioning"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools-git-versioning]
enabled = true

...

[project]
version = "1.0"
...
```

According to documentation, the `enabled` flag should suffice for `setuptools` to get the tag-based version and set it as the version of the package, yet when building the package, the version prompted when running `python3 -m pip list` or `conda list` corresponds to the hard-coded value of version in the `project` section of `pyproject.toml`.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [PyPa documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#declaring-project-metadata-the-project-table) when `version` is defined statically it can't be changed by a tool (i.e. setuptools-git-versioning in this case). The other option is to use [dynamic](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/#dynamic) which...

> Dynamic metadata is listed via the `dynamic` field (defined later in
> this specification) and represents metadata that a tool will later
> provide.

So removing the static `version = "1.0"` and adding `dynamic = ["version"]` to the `[project]` should work.

Comment: I just incorporated this into my own project. Thanks for your answer